# Maven deploying to central api incompatibility

Tags: maven, nexus, maven-central

I wrote a Java library and would like to upload this to the maven central repository, however when I run the deploy phase using VScode it gives the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonatype.plugins:nexus-staging-maven-plugin:1.6.8:deploy (injected-nexus-deploy) on project botlibrary: 
Execution injected-nexus-deploy of goal org.sonatype.plugins:nexus-staging-maven-plugin:1.6.8:deploy failed: 
An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.sonatype.plugins:nexus-staging-maven-plugin:1.6.8:deploy: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    extension>org.sonatype.plugins:nexus-staging-maven-plugin:1.6.8
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
```

If it helps, my nexus stagin plugin is configured like this:

```
       <plugin>
        <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.8</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
          <serverId>ossrh</serverId>
          <nexusUrl>https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/</nexusUrl>
          <autoReleaseAfterClose>true</autoReleaseAfterClose>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

full pom file (too much code for the post): https://github.com/MichaPehlivan/Discord-Bot-Library/blob/master/pom.xml

IDE: VScode (using the maven plugin to deploy)

JDK version: 16.0.2

Maven version: 3.8.2

What does the error mean? And how can I fix it?

Comment: Please post full pom file, which JDK version, which Maven version and from where you are calling the build to deploy the artifacts?

Comment: @khmarbaise I added the additional info

Comment: First I would suggest to remove the configuration of nexus-staging-maven-plugin and use the usual way via maven-deploy-plugin etc. to reduce the number of options which could cause that problem is...

Comment: Yes thank you this fixed it.

Comment: Maybe this: https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-27902